# Python scripts of GRASS in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, python

I want to use v.kriger from GRASS through sextante QGIS 2.0, but this command is not here. But I find, in C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-7.0.svn\scripts, the command as a python script.
How can I use this command in qgis?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, you must use it from GRASS GIS.

In the beginning of the script:

```
import grass.script as grass
```

It is just a front-end to [R](http://www.r-project.org/). The dependencies  are:

- R software >= 2.x
- the Python module [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/) (Python binding to R)
- the R packages [automap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/automap/), [gstat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/index.html), [spgrass6](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spgrass6/index.html) (Interface between GRASS GIS and R) and [rgeos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) ([automap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/automap/) optional)

[image]

There is also [v.autokrige](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_AddOns#v.autokrige), with the same problems

[image]

Comment: Thanks to information. But I want to implement the kriging script in the qgis plugin that I am developing. This can't be doing?

Comment: You need to use R from Python with the rpy2 module (look at [Kriging in R in Python](http://blog.technokrat.nl/?p=409), for example)